# Как работает <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>. Горит красным в среде IntellijIdea

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, spring-mvc

Копирую из старого проекта файлы конфигурации Spring. Но думаю, дело не в этом. На картинке видно, что свойство location горит красным и ошибка - Cannot resolve...
Я так думаю, тут что-то с контекстом связано. И переменная classpath тоже горит красным. Что я не так сделал? Если нужно еще скрины настроек(и прочего скину)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что ваши файлы забыли в `webapp`, почему не в `resources` ?  И да необезательно что спринг не будет читать конфиги, ide иногда ругаеться, но билдиться нормально

Comment: В другом проекте  тот же самый файл  и код работают нормально. И они тоже расположены в папке web-app. Разве эти конфиги должны в папке resources? Объясните пожалуйста

Comment: Стандарты, ты можешь поставить файлы и в java папку. Но по стандарту все .java файлы пишуться в java папке, все конфигурации и нужные файлы для работы кода в resources. Все что связанно с web-ом в webapp (views, css, js, etc). Так что создай папку `spring` в ресурсах и закинь туда все файлы. Вот тебе проект в помощь https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic

Comment: Про стандарт это Вы батенька глупость сказали: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html